# Unordered inline list with RTL

Tags: html

Strange multilingual question here:

I have a `<ul>` with `<li>` items that are displayed with `display:inline`.

When I use a `body{direction:rtl}` style directive, these items do not change order.
Is there any trick to inverse the order of the `<li>` items for RTL (e.g. arabic) language support?

Comment: have you tried adding `dir="rtl"` to your body tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the rule

```
ul { unicode-bidi: bidi-override; }
```

Caveat: Depending on browser, this may also cause a string like “1234” to be displayed right to left. You may need to set `unicode-bidi: bidi-override; direction: rtl` on such elements.

According to the [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-direction) spec, the `direction` property “specifies the base writing direction of blocks and the direction of embeddings and overrides (see 'unicode-bidi') for the Unicode bidirectional algorithm. In addition, it specifies such things as the direction of table column layout, the direction of horizontal overflow, the position of an incomplete last line in a block in case of 'text-align: justify'.” But inline box ordering is not affected. Later, it adds:

“For the 'direction' property to affect reordering in inline elements, the 'unicode-bidi' property's value must be 'embed' or 'override'.”

This is a bit vague, but the the code above works on modern browsers (which otherwise exhibit many differences in dealing with directionality).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe if you add?

```
​ul li {
    float:right;
}​
```

But if it comes to ordering lists, you should use `ol` instead of `ul`.

Comment: This will only change the positioning, not the direction

Comment: e.g. he wants "some text" to become "txet emos"

Comment: It will order the items from right to left, I thought this is exactly what he wants?! Anyway, for me it works just with rtl … http://jsfiddle.net/Vtwqs/1/

Answer (score 1):

Changing the direction will only move the items to be on the right or left side of the screen. It will not change the ORDER of the items inside the `ul`.
To change the order you can use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) like this:

```
ul = $('#my-ul'); // your parent ul element
ul.children().each(function(i,li){ul.prepend(li)})
```